# Linear function inverse

Tags: linear-algebra

I have two monotonically increasing piecewise-linear functions:

\begin{align}
F_{L}(s) &= s_L\\
F_{H}(s) &= s_H
\end{align}

and their inverses:

\begin{align}
F_{L}^{-1}(s_L) &= s\\
F_{H}^{-1}(s_H) &= s
\end{align}

How can I find the function :

\begin{align}
F_{M}( (1-h)s_L +hs_H ) &= s \\
\end{align}

where $h \in [0,1]$

Can I calculate $F_M$ in terms of the other functions?

The ranges of $F_L$, $F_H$ and $s$ are in $[0,1]$, if that makes any difference.

Comment: How come $F_M$ has two arguments, but $F_M^{-1}$ returns only one?

Comment: No, that makes even less sense. If $F_M$ has two inputs and one output, then $F_M^{-1}$ has one input and two outputs, not two inputs and one ouput.

Comment: Ok I think that the current formulation of the problem is what I'm looking after - I hope it's clearer, still not sure if what I'm asking is possible though. I know all details about $F_L$,$F_H$ and their inverses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I take it that $h$ is given and you're forming the convex combination $F_C=(1-h)F_L+hF_H$ of the two piecewise linear functions, which is again piecewise linear. You know the inverses of $F_L$ and $F_H$, and you want to find the inverse of $F_C$, which you denote by $F_M=F_C^{-1}$.

As Marc has pointed out, $F_C$ is not necessarily invertible. However, assuming that $F_L$ and $F_H$ are (strictly) monotonic in the same direction, $F_C$ is also (strictly) monotonic, an hence invertible.

I don't think you can express its inverse in terms of the other functions; you can just apply the same process that gave you $F_L^{-1}$ from $F_L$ and $F_H^{-1}$ from $F_H$ to $F_C$ to give you $F_C^{-1}$, since $F_C$ is also piecewise linear. If for some reason you can't do that, I don't see how you could use $F_L^{-1}$ and $F_H^{-1}$ to construct $F_C^{-1}$, since you wouldn't know which arguments to apply them to, since a value of $F_C$ could have been assembled from different pairs of values of $F_L$ and $F_H$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As you said $F_C$ is invertible, but I'm not sure if I can apply the same process. I can calculate the inverses of $F_L$ and $F_H$ as I have all the data points that make these functions. I was trying to calculate $F_C^{-1}$ as the function that interpolates between $F_L^{-1}$ and $F_H^{-1}$, but not as $F_C^{-1}(s) = (1-h)F_L^{-1}(s) +hF_H^{-1}(s)$, but by calculating $F_C^{-1}(s)$ if $F_C(s) = (1-h)F_L(s) +hF_H(s)$

Comment: @Babis: Yes, certainly, that first equation you write would be wrong. If you're inverting $F_L$ and $F_H$ on the basis of having all the data points, you can do the same thing for $F_C$: The set of interval boundaries is the union of the two sets of interval boundaries for $F_L$ and $F_H$, and the slope on each interval is the sum of the two slopes of $F_L$ and $F_H$ on that interval.

Comment: You write that for $F_C$ the interval boundary is the union and the slope is the sum of the original functions. But how does $h$ affect it then?

Comment: @Babis: Sorry, that was a mistake; I didn't have the whole question in mind and thought that you were just adding the functions. The set of interval boundaries (not: the interval boundary) will still be the union of the two sets, but the slope will be given by the same convex combination used to form $F_C$, i.e. where $F_L$ has slope $m_L$ and $F_H$ has slope $m_H$, $F_C=(1-h)F_L+hF_H$ has slope $m_C=(1-h)m_L+hm_H$ (since slope is linear).

Comment: Thanks again for the clarifications and support, I need to try to make it work now.

Answer (score 1):

With no more information than in the question, there is no guarantee that $(1-h)S_L+hS_H$ is invertible in the first place. For instance whenver $F_L=-F_H$, one gets for $h=\frac12$ that $(1-h)S_L+hS_H=0$. This circumstance should destroy any hope of finding a pleasant formula for $F_M^{-1}$ in this general setting.

Comment: Perhaps it was meant to be implied that $F_L$ and $F_H$ are monotonic in the same direction.

Comment: Perhaps, but there is no point in guessing omitted hypotheses. When asking a question OP should make sure to **mention all assumptions** that are made.

Comment: I couldn't agree more :-)

Comment: The ranges of all functions are in $[0,1]$ and are indeed monotonically increasing - sorry for not mentioning it.